# Running StyleGAN 2 on CPU

Tags: tensorflow, stylegan

Is it possible to run the TensorFlow version of [stylegan2](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2) on the CPU? If, then what are the changes need to be made for it?

Comment: I am also looking for the same , does anyone know how to run it on CPU ? @Thunder

Comment: I Haven't got any source yet. The main part where stylegan2 uses GPU is in their in-built CUDA kernels. But I've checked on their ops files (https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan2/tree/master/dnnlib/tflib/ops), and there is 'ref' implementation that allows to run it on CPU. After setting impl='ref' instead of impl='cuda' everywhere and setting device used=CPU everywhere, I got stuck with an error(Don't remember exactly) which was related to data format( NCHW, NHWC)